# fragment opened on activity not staying at right side of the screen

Tags: android, android-fragments, transition

I have an activity in the landscape mode and on some button click the fragment appears. it adds up but to the left of the screen. But i want to add it to the right of the screen and close it to the right itself.

I am unable to have appropriate animations. How do i do this?

this is the enter transition

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shareInterpolator="false" >

<translate
    android:duration="700"
    android:fromXDelta="50%"
    android:toXDelta="170%"
    android:startOffset="150" />
<alpha
    android:fromAlpha="0.0"
    android:toAlpha="1.0"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime" />

</set>
```

Comment: do you want right to left transition?

Comment: yes right to left  but to stay at the right border of the screen .. right now it goes to the left border

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For right to left transition

**right_in.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate
        android:duration="700"
        android:fromXDelta="100%"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
        android:toXDelta="0%" />
</set>
```

**right_out.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate
        android:duration="700"
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
        android:toXDelta="-100%" />
</set>
```

now when starting intent add following line:

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.right_out, R.anim.right_in);
```

Comment: i have this solution but this does not indent the fragment once entered from right to the right of the screen

Comment: thank divya. but solution is to add X scaling to it . Done it myself.